# Mongodb will automatically shut down even though permissions are correctly set

Tags: mongodb, macos

[Read/Write permissions set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vN05p.png)

[Mongodb still won't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rofli.png)

I used brew to install mongodb and updated it and everything. 
I used [this](https://treehouse.github.io/installation-guides/mac/mongo-mac.html) tutorial to download and install. I was able to do everything listed but when I tried mongod it didn't work. I've had mongodb downloaded and working previously on my laptop but had to factory reset recently and now it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think mongod instance could not create the lock file or a lock file is already present in the location. Which means the current instance cannot get hold of it.

Remove the current lock file and restart your service.

```
sudo rm /data/db/mongod.lock
```

Restart

```
brew services stop mongodb
brew services start mongodb
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked the version? I think when you can successfully check the version, it means your mongodb is ok and have been installed properly.

Here's how to check mongodb version "mongod --version".